# Python - Is it possible to have a dictionary in a list?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'y new to writing scripts in Python but I know you can have a list inside a dictionary but can you have a dictionary inside a list?

My example is i'm trying to execute a script on a list of linux servers. I have do it with one dictionary as such (the details are blocked for obvious reasons):

```
list1 = {
'IP_' : '@IPADDR',
'Username_' : '@USER',
'Password_' : '@PASSWD',
'dirlocation' : '@DIR'
}
```

and then...

```
    ssh.connect(list1['IP_'], port=22, username=list1['Username_'], password=list1['Password_'])
```

but is it possible to have something like:

```
ServerList = {

list1 = {
'IP_' : '@IPADDR',
'Username_' : '@USER',
'Password_' : '@PASSWD',
'dirlocation' : '@DIR'
}

list2 = {
'IP_' : '@IPADDR',
'Username_' : '@USER',
'Password_' : '@PASSWD',
'dirlocation' : '@DIR'
}
}
```

and then create a loop as such?

```
for listobj in ServerList:
    ssh.connect(ServerList.listobj['IP_'], port=22, username=listobj['Username_'], password=listobj['Password_'])
```

This is probably what some would see to be a silly question but many thanks for you help!

Comment: Yes, try it! In fact, what you have in `ServerList` is a dict of dicts `{{..}, {..}}`. A list of dicts is `[{..}, {..}]`, which is not uncommon. Make sure to put the comma between each dict, as your example currently is missing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible. You can either have a dict of dict:

```
>>> ServerDict = {
...
... 'list1': {
... 'IP_' : '@IPADDR1',
... 'Username_' : '@USER',
... 'Password_' : '@PASSWD',
... 'dirlocation' : '@DIR'
... },
...
... 'list2': {
... 'IP_' : '@IPADDR2',
... 'Username_' : '@USER',
... 'Password_' : '@PASSWD',
... 'dirlocation' : '@DIR'
... }
... }
```

Or a list:

```
>>> ServerList = [
...
...  {
... 'IP_' : '@IPADDR1',
... 'Username_' : '@USER',
... 'Password_' : '@PASSWD',
... 'dirlocation' : '@DIR'
... },
...
...  {
... 'IP_' : '@IPADDR2',
... 'Username_' : '@USER',
... 'Password_' : '@PASSWD',
... 'dirlocation' : '@DIR'
... }
... ]
```

And you can iterate through the dict

```
>>> for k,v in ServerDict.items():
...  print k, v['IP_']
...
list1 @IPADDR1
list2 @IPADDR2
>>> for k in ServerDict.keys():
...   print ServerDict[k]['IP_']
...
@IPADDR1
@IPADDR2
>>> for v in ServerDict.values():
...   print v['IP_']
...
@IPADDR1
@IPADDR2
```

or the list:

```
>>> for i in ServerList:
...   print i['IP_']
...
@IPADDR1
@IPADDR2
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to have a list of dict items:

```
>>> foo = [ {'a':1,'b':2} , {'c':3,'d':4} ]
>>> foo[1]
{'c': 3, 'd': 4}
>>>
```